# Express solution in simplest radical form: $(4x-1)(3x+7) = (5x-1)(2x+3)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, factoring

I need help with the problem. I'm in grade 11 math.

$(4x-1)(3x+7)=(5x-1)(2x+3)$

So far I think I have to factor it and I got $(12x^2+25x-7)=(10x^2-13x-3)$

Thanks!

Comment: Please [use MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your questions to be more readable

Comment: (in this question you can just put dollar signs around all the formulas and it's enough to format it)

Comment: Expand both sides (i.e., multiply out all terms), then subtract one side from the other to get a quadratic equation.  Then solve this equation using the quadratic formula.

Comment: Good, then $(12x^2+25x-7)-(10x^2-13x-3)=0$, that reduces to the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$ that you probably know how to do.

Comment: Nitpick.  You started out with them factor.  Multiplying them together is called "expanding"  Now subtract like terms for both sides to get $2x^2 +38x -4 = 0$. and solve that (maybe be factoring.... or maybe be quadratic formula... although I was suggest dividing both sides by $2$ to get $x^2 + 18x -2 = 0$. )  Hint: you can't factor....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there! Note first that the sign of $13x$ on the right side is positive, not negative. Let's move all of the terms to one side $$12x^2+25x-7-10x^2-13x+3=0$$Let's combine like terms$$2x^2+12x-4=0\to x^2+6x-2=0$$Finally, we use the quadratic formula to find the roots, which are$$x=\color{red}{-3\pm\sqrt{11}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have an equation, the best course of action is usually to collect all like terms; in this case, all like powers: This means, assemble the $12x^2$ and $10x^2$ on the different sides to one single $2x^2$ on the left-hand side, and so on. Doing so, you arrive that the equation $2x^2 +12x-4 = 0$. This is a kind of equation you have probably(?) seen before.

Comment: Your quadratic is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it now